# Override properties CSS3 Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

Hello I'm trying to override the properties in the input, because I'm make a site to web and I'need the desing for a normal pc( web responsive). For example the nex loggin form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Example </title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resouce/css/loggin.css" />

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Loggin</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div id="formulario">
    <form method="POST" action="" data-ajax="false">
        <label for="usuarioLogin">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="usuarioLogin" id="usuarioLogin" /><br>
        <label for="passwordLogin">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" id="passwordLogin" /><br>
        <button id="ingresarLogin" type="submit" data-theme="a">Ingresar</button>
    </form>
</div>


</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

the *loggin.css* contains the override css code, It's the code :

```
@media all and (max-width: 1280px)
{
.ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset
    {
       width:300px;
    }
}
```

How to override the width the input-text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override CSS properties once with the `!important` flag:

```
.ui-input-text
{
    width: 200px !important;
}
```